# Page not rendered when sending statuscode 500 to the client

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, http-status-codes

I have a page (generic handler) on which I want to return the status code 500 to the client to indicate that something is wrong. I do it like this:

```
Response.StatusCode = 500;
Response.StatusDescription = "Internal Server Error";
```

And at the same time I render a friendly message telling the user that something went wrong.
But instead of seing my message, I get the default IIS message saying something like this:

> Server Error
>   500 - Internal server error.
>   There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

And if I go in to IIS and remove the error page for 500, I get this message:

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

It works as intended in IIS6, but not in IIS7. What should I do to get it working in IIS7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need one more line in there to bypass IIS7 taking over (based on the 500 error code you set):

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

Reference: [HttpResponse.TrySkipIisCustomErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors.aspx?ppud=4)