# How to throw HTTP errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, response.redirect

I am using Response.Redirect to redirect the user to a new page but I want the page to be shown only if there is a particular parameter in the query string. Otherwise, I want an HTTP 401 authentication error page to be shown. Can that be done? If yes, how? If not, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your page, you could redirect to an `IHttpHandler` that would output the content for your authentication error page and would set the HTTP status code to 401.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write("Authentication error");
    context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
}
```

The [MSDN topic for IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) as some links that may help you understand what is an HTTP handler and how you can implement one. The most important ones are:

[HTTP Handlers and HTTP Modules Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb398986(v=VS.90).aspx)

[Walkthrough: Creating a Synchronous HTTP Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090(v=VS.90).aspx)

[How to: Register HTTP Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy(v=VS.90).aspx)

Comment: Are you sure this works? Have you checked the header? EDIT: seems you might be right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288797/page-not-rendered-when-sending-statuscode-500-to-the-client however this is still redirection.

Comment: @Codesleuth, indeed, this will depend on redirection. Also thanks for the link, I wasn't aware of that particular detail for IIS7.

Comment: How to use this IHttpHandler in my code? What should be the context parameter I should input? Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: Might as well delete my incorrect answer, since this works. Also, thanks! I'll be changing my old code to use this :)

Answer (score 2):

The following returns a 401 status code, you will need to add the HTML to display yourself depending how IIS is configured.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["RedirectParam"]))
            Response.StatusCode = 401; 
        else
            Response.Redirect("redirectpage.html");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the answer myself, with some help from Joao and the answers provided by others..

I simply have to write this:

```
 if (Request.Params[param] != nul)
            {
               ...
            }
            else
            {
                Response.ContentType = "text/html";
                Response.Write("Authentication error");
                Response.StatusCode = 401;
                Response.End();
            }
```

Simple! :) Let me know if there's any potential issue with this!

Comment: Which is identical what I said an hour ago. Glad you have fixed it :)

Comment: Yea but I didn't want to create a new redirection page and I had no idea about responses one hour back. :D